# Spring JPA property to select objects that contains fields from List

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have entity Recipe:

```
public class Recipe extends BaseEntity{
// other fields

@Column(name = "ingredients")
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "ingredients_recipes",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;
```

Ingredient:

```
public class Ingredient extends BaseEntity {
private String name;

@Column(name = "recipes")
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "ingredients", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Recipe> recipes;
```

I need to select all recipes that contain all or less ingredients from a List. I tried

```
Set<Recipe> findAllByIngredientsIn(List<Ingredient> ingredientList);
```

but it checks that the recipe has each ingredient individually. If I give only salt in ingredientList, it return recipes with salt and peper(or other ingredients), but I need to get recipes that only have salt. Is there a jpa repository method that I can use, or I need only a custom query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a jpa repository method that I can use, or I need only a custom query?

No you'll have to come up with your own query and use it in a `@Query` annotation.

Comment: When i use 
@Query(value = "select r from Recipe r where r.ingredients in (:ingredientList)")
Set<Recipe> findAllByIngredientsIn(List<Ingredient> ingredientList);
I get an error Parameter value [Ingredient{name='salt'}] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
Do you know why?

Comment: You probably have to use `r.ingredients.id` and a `List<Long>` or whatever types your ids are. You might also do the transformation from `List<Ingredient>` to `List<Long>` in a SpEL. If that does not solve the problem, please create a new question for it.